Why Do Pearson Residuals Often Show Positive Values on One Diagonal and Negative on the Other, Even Without Variable Association?
I'm analyzing a contingency table using a Chi-square test and noticed an interesting pattern in the Pearson residuals. Specifically, I often see that the residuals tend to be positive along one diagonal and negative along the other, even when there's no apparent association between the row and column variables.
My understanding is that Pearson residuals are calculated based on the difference between observed and expected frequencies, scaled by the square root of the expected frequency. However, I’m puzzled as to why this diagonal pattern of residuals occurs when the variables are independent.
To illustrate this, I created the following example in R:
# Set a random seed for reproducibility
set.seed(42)

# Generate two independent random samples of size 10,000
x <- sample(-50:50, 10000, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(-50:50, 10000, replace = TRUE)

# Create a contingency table by categorizing the samples into positive and non-positive values
t <- table(x > 0, y > 0)

# Perform the Chi-square test
c <- chisq.test(t)

# Display the Pearson residuals
c$residuals

       
             FALSE       TRUE
  FALSE -0.8678288  0.8788332
  TRUE   0.8825329 -0.8937237


In this example, x and y are independent random samples, and we categorize them into positive or non-positive values. Even though x and y are independent, the residuals exhibit a pattern where positive values appear on one diagonal and negative values on the other.
Is this pattern related to the way expected values are calculated, or is there some other underlying reason why residuals tend to behave this way? I'd appreciate any insights or explanations!

Can you show an example demonstrate your observation? Did you assume an $I\times J$ table with $I=J$? Pearson residuals are scaled by the square root of the expected frequency.

@ZackFisher Thank you for your comment. I’ve updated my question.

For a $2\times 2$ contingency table, this is almost inevitable.   Essentially there is a negative correlation between cells in the same row or column (the weighted sum across a row or a column is $0$ so you must have opposite signs when there are only two terms) and so a positive correlation along diagonals.

@Henry, this is the explanation I've been looking for. Thanks!

I commented: For a $2×2$ contingency table, this is almost inevitable. Essentially there is a negative correlation between cells in the same row or column (the weighted sum across a row or a column is $0$ so you must have opposite signs when there are only two terms) and so a positive correlation along diagonals.
Suppose your observations are: $\begin{matrix} a & b\\ c & d
\end{matrix}$.
Then your Pearson residuals are: $\begin{matrix} \dfrac{a - \frac{(a+b)(a+c)}{a+b+c+d}}{\sqrt{\frac{(a+b)(a+c)}{a+b+c+d}}} & \dfrac{b - \frac{(a+b)(b+d)}{a+b+c+d}}{\sqrt{\frac{(a+b)(b+d)}{a+b+c+d}}}\\  \dfrac{c - \frac{(c+d)(a+c)}{a+b+c+d}}{\sqrt{\frac{(c+d)(a+c)}{a+b+c+d}}} & \dfrac{d - \frac{(c+d)(b+d)}{a+b+c+d}}{\sqrt{\frac{(c+d)(b+d)}{a+b+c+d}}}
\end{matrix}$.
The denominators in the Pearson residuals are positive, while looking at the numerators in the top row $\left(a - \frac{(a+b)(a+c)}{a+b+c+d}\right) + \left(b - \frac{(a+b)(b+d)}{a+b+c+d}\right) =0$, so those Pearson residuals have opposite signs; the same is true for the other row and columns.  So one of the following is true:

the first and fourth Pearson residuals are positive and the second and third are negative
the first and fourth Pearson residuals are negative and the second and third are positive
all four Pearson residuals are zero

and this phenomenon is what you have observed.

You also have $\left(a - \frac{(a+b)(a+c)}{a+b+c+d}\right) = \left(d - \frac{(c+d)(b+d)}{a+b+c+d}\right)$  and similarly on the other diagonal

This is to explore the "sum to zero" fact within the same row or the same column of residuals given by @Henry.
The raw residuals in an $I\times J$ table from Pearson's $\chi^2$ test can be alternatively obtained from fitting a Poisson log-linear model on the table with cells
$$Y_{ij}\sim\text{Poisson}(\mu_{ij}), 
$$
where
$$\log(\mu_{ij})=\alpha_i+\beta_j, 
$$
$\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$ are row and column parameters. Because there is no interaction between the rows and columns, the MLE fit is $\hat\mu_{ij}=Y_{i\cdot}Y_{\cdot j}/Y_{\cdot\cdot}$, the same as expected counts from the Pearson $\chi^2$ test.
If we collect all $Y_{ij}$ as a vector $Y$ and collect $\hat{\mu}_{ij}$ as a vector $\hat\mu$, and let $X$ be the design matrix for the Poisson log-linear model, then  the likelihood equation is
$$X^T(Y-\hat\mu)=0. 
$$
Let $X_{\text{row}}$ be the $IJ\times I$ matrix of indicator variables coding the row membership. Then $ X_{\text{row}}$ is in the column space of $X$ since the model included a row effect $\alpha_i$. That is, there exists a matrix $L$ such that $ X_{\text{row}}=XL$. So the row sums of raw residuals are
$$X_{\text{row}}^T(Y-\hat\mu)=L^TX^T(Y-\hat\mu)=L^T0=0,  
$$
confirming that the marginals of raw residual $I\times J$ table are zero.

The above result can be generalized to models
$$\log(\mu_{ij})=\alpha_i+\beta_j+\sum_{k=1}^q \gamma_k s_{ijk}
$$
where $s_{ijk}$ are some known predictors and $\gamma_k$ are additional parameters. If $q=0$, this is the above independence model. If $q>0$, this allows some degree of interaction.
Following the same reasoning, we still have the same result in such models, i.e., the marginal sums of raw residuals are zero.

By examining the likelihood equation from the GLM with link function $g$
$$X^T D V^{-1}(Y-\mu)=0
$$
where $V=\text{diag}[\mathbb{V}(Y)]$ and $D=\text{diag}\left\lbrace \left[g'(\mu)\right]^{-1}\right\rbrace$,
it can be seen that if we replace the link $g(\mu)=\log(\mu)$ by $g(\mu)=\sqrt{\mu}$ in the Poisson GLM, then the likelihood equation will become
$$X^T\hat{V}^{-1/2}(Y-\hat{\mu}) =0 
$$
where $\hat{V}=\text{diag}(\hat\mu)$. In other words, $\hat{V}^{-1/2}(Y-\hat{\mu})$ is the Pearson residual for this model using square root link. Again,  following the previous reasoning, the marginal sums of the Pearson residual table are zero, although these Pearson residuals are no longer the same as those in the conventional Pearson's $\chi^2$ test.
